# Separated server is needed for remote event recevier?

Tags: 2016, remote-event-receiver, topology

We are using SP2010 and planning to upgrade to SP2016 on-premise. I do not have experience in "App model" development.

On our SP2010 farm (enterprise edition) we have various event receiver built with farm solution. As far as I know they are no longer supported in 2016. We need to rebuild in "remote event receiver" model.

However, [SharePoint-hosted add-ins do not support remote event receivers. To use remote event receivers, you need to use a provider-hosted add-in](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/solution-guidance/use-remote-event-receivers-in-sharepoint).

Currently, we planned to build SP2016 farm with: 2 WFE, 2 APP, 2 Office online server. My question is, do we need to setup an additional server for "provider-hosted" app? If so, what is the software requirement for this server? Just need a standard windows 2016 with IIS?

Comment: I think if your SP2010 farm solution has event receivers then it would work in SP2016 on premise version as well. You don't need to convert them in remote event receivers. And if you want to create remote event receivers, you can host them in IIS or other dedicated server also.

Comment: @DikeshGandhi So I cannot host remote event receiver on SharePoint server and office online server, right?

Comment: If you want then you can host them in IIS same as web application. But I want to say: "your event receivers in site will work in SP2016. You no need to convert them in remote event receivers."